# Assigning value to item within an arraylist by index

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist

I have this VB.NET `ArrayList` object which is working quite well. I have built it like this. It's the first one I have used.

```
Public Class MyObj
    Private _str1 As String
    Private _str2 As String

    Public Property Str1() As String
      Get
        Return _str1
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
        _str1 = value
      End Set
    End Property

     Public Property Str2() As String
       Get
         Return _str2
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As String)
        _str2 = value
       End Set
     End Property   

     Public Sub New(ByRef pStr1 As String)
      _str1 = pStr1
     End Sub
 End Class
```

Then I initiialise it doing this...

```
Dim MyObj1 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
MyObj1.Add(New MyObj("myTestString"))
```

So this is all working later on. So I pack up the arraylist and store it in a class level variable. Then in a different method I grab my arraylist. I then want to assign a value to `_str2`. Does anyone have advice on how I would go about this. I keep trying to know avail. This is the sort of thing I mean.

```
For i = 0 To MyObj1.Items.Count - 1
    MyObj1.Item(i)("Str2") = "tesstring2"
Next
```

Comment: Use a `LIst(Of MyObj)` instead of an `ArrayList`. That prevents you from  always casting the object and makes the code also more readable. Actually there is no reason to use an `ArrayList` anymore.

Comment: i do recommend you to use `LIst(Of MyObj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim wrote, you will be better off using a List instead of the old ArrayList.

To set it up and then access the property `Str2` of the instances of `MyObj`:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of MyObj)
myList.Add(New MyObj("Hello"))

For i = 0 To myList.Count - 1
    myList(i).Str2 = "World"
Next
```

Notice how it is `.Str2`, not `("Str2")`.

Comment: I did it with the List(of MyObj) exactly how you have written. Thanks for all your great advice.